# How to allocate huge pages in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory

I am studying transparent huge page (THP) in Linux.

I am trying to call `__get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP, mysize)` to ask kernel to allocate 2MB huge pages for me.

So I want to know:

1. If kernel really allocate huge page for me?
2. How can I check the kernel page table for that allocated page to make sure it is huge page.

Comment: Are you allocating from user space or kernel space? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548260/madvisedodump-on-the-same-ptr-size-as-a-successful-madvisedontdump-fails-wit) shows the page has flags indicating huge pages. Transparent pages are handle by the kernel and are a bit  different from just huge pages.

Comment: I would like to get huge page from kernel space, i.e. in kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on kernel memory allocation is in the source at Documentation/core-api/memory-allocation.rst

A number of APIs in include/linux/vmalloc.h take vm_flags of which VM_HUGETLB can be one of those flags.

Not a complete answer however I'm hoping its in the right direction.

Comment: I did a test again, with kmalloc(0x200000, GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_COMP), and the kernel returned me a 2MB huge page, this is what I want.

Comment: Oh good. Because when I posted https://marc.info/?l=linux-mm&m=153828641520732&w=2 I did assume that VM_HUGETLB was restricted to userspace processes.

Comment: Oh, i did read your codes weeks ago, and at that time, i could NOT get the point, since i seldom use hugetlbfs. I need more time to figure out your code changes.  My assumption is current Linux kernel (4.x) will use huge page by default, for userspace processes. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Userspace under Transparent Huge Pages might aggregated general memory allocation into a huge page, otherwise explicit huge pages are obtainable using mmap and shmget flags. While your kernel allocation did get a hugepage, it probably didn't have the VM_HUGETLB flags on it right?

Comment: As you said, VM_HUGETLB should be for userspace process.  And I did was to call kmalloc(0x200000, GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), to get a 2MB page for kernel use, not for the process.

Comment: @wangt13 How did you verify that kmalloc did indeed return a huge page?

Comment: @andreas, I checked the page table entry for the allocated page, and it points to a 2MB page.