# madvise(DODUMP) on the same ptr/size as a successful madvise(DONTDUMP) fails with EINVAL

Tags: c, linux, memory, system-calls

Testing a MariaDB anomaly of mysqld (10.3 branch) what it does is on startup:

A memory allocation returns `ptr=0x7fffe1a00000` for `bytes=2097152`

Before the madvise syscall, the /proc/{pid}/smap entry is:

```
7fffe1a00000-7fffe1c00000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 18481215                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
Size:               2048 kB
KernelPageSize:     2048 kB
MMUPageSize:        2048 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr sh mr mw me ms de ht sd
```

After the call:

```
madvise(ptr, bytes, MADV_DONTDUMP)
```

The page picks up the `dd` "don't dump" flags as expected:

```
7fffe1a00000-7fffe1c00000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 18481215                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
Size:               2048 kB
KernelPageSize:     2048 kB
MMUPageSize:        2048 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr sh mr mw me ms de ht dd sd
```

sometime later just before `madvise(ptr, m_size, MADV_DODUMP)` the map is the same:

```
7fffe1a00000-7fffe1c00000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 18481215                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
Size:               2048 kB
KernelPageSize:     2048 kB
MMUPageSize:        2048 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr sh mr mw me ms de ht dd sd
```

The next code is:

```
madvise(ptr, m_size, MADV_DODUMP)
```

GDB shows the same values are used:

```
(gdb) p size
$1 = 2097152
(gdb) p ptr
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffe1a00000
```

`madvise(ptr,size,MADV_DODUMP)` is returns -1, `errno=EINVAL`, and the page map remains the same.

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.18.9-300.fc29.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 20 02:32:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For completeness, a `strace -fe trace=%memory ...` extract from allocation to `EINVAL` of the same program (different execution):

```
[pid  6036] shmat(18874431, NULL, 0)    = 0x7f6ebda00000
[pid  6036] madvise(0x7f6ebda00000, 2097152, MADV_DONTDUMP) = 0
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 2215936, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ebd7e3000
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa0d76000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa0de7000)         = 0x55caa0de7000
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa0de7000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa0e38000)         = 0x55caa0e38000
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa0e38000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa0e8a000)         = 0x55caa0e8a000
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ebcfe2000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6ebcfe3000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6039 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ebc7e1000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6ebc7e2000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6040 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ead3ff000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6ead400000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6041 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eacbfe000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eacbff000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6042 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eac3fd000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eac3fe000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6043 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eabbfc000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eabbfd000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6044 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eab3fb000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eab3fc000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6045 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eaabfa000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eaabfb000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6046 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6eaa3f9000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6eaa3fa000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6047 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ea9bf8000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6ea9bf9000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6048 attached
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ea93f7000
[pid  6036] mprotect(0x7f6ea93f8000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
strace: Process 6049 attached
[pid  6049] mmap(NULL, 134217728, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ea13f7000
[pid  6049] munmap(0x7f6ea13f7000, 46174208) = 0
[pid  6049] munmap(0x7f6ea8000000, 20934656) = 0
[pid  6049] mprotect(0x7f6ea4000000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa0e8a000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa0eab000)         = 0x55caa0eab000
[pid  6036] mmap(NULL, 2117632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ebc5dc000
[pid  6036] munmap(0x7f6ebd7e3000, 2215936) = 0
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa0eab000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa10d5000)         = 0x55caa10d5000
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa10d5000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa1118000)         = 0x55caa1118000
[pid  6036] brk(NULL)                   = 0x55caa1118000
[pid  6036] brk(0x55caa115c000)         = 0x55caa115c000
[pid  6036] madvise(0x7f6ebda00000, 2097152, MADV_DODUMP) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Any clues as to why the EINVAL is returned for `madvise(MADV_DODUMP)`?

code is: mariadb-10.3 branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`de` refers to `VM_DONTEXPAND`, and the kernel explicitly rejects that flag for `MADV_DODUMP`:

```
#define VM_SPECIAL (VM_IO | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_PFNMAP | VM_MIXEDMAP)
…
    case MADV_DODUMP:
            if (new_flags & VM_SPECIAL) {
                    error = -EINVAL;
                    goto out;
            }
            new_flags &= ~VM_DONTDUMP;
            break;
```

This check has been present since commit 0103bd16fb90bc741c7a03fd1ea4e8a505abad23 (“mm: prepare `VM_DONTDUMP` for using in drivers”) in 2012.

This mapping probably comes from hugetlbfs (`hugetlbfs_file_mmap` in `fs/hugetlbfs/inode.c`) because the `ht` bit is set as well.

Comment: It quite rightly was allocated with `shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (size_t) size, SHM_HUGETLB | SHM_R | SHM_W)`. Setting `sysctl vm.nr_hugepages=0` avoided the error. Feel slightly cheated by `man 2 madvise` that implies `MADV_DODUMP` undoes `MADV_DONTDUMP`. I'll get over it :-) and thanks.

Comment: As it happens, I [wrote a kernel patch](https://marc.info/?l=linux-mm&m=153828641520732&w=2) to fix this.

Comment: Fixed in 4.19+ kernels and stable kernels starting at 4.18.14, 4.14.76, 4.9.133, 4.4.161, and 3.18.124